# ksql table adds extra characters to rowkey

Tags: avro, ksqldb

I have some kafka topics with avro format, I created an stream and a table to be able to join with ksql, but the result of the join comes always as null.

Following the troubleshoot, I found that the key is prepended with some character, which dependes on the length of the string. I suppose it has to do with something about avro, but I can't find where is the problem.

```
CREATE TABLE entity_table ( Id VARCHAR,    Info info )
WITH
(
KAFKA_TOPIC = 'pisos',
VALUE_FORMAT='avro',
KEY = 'Id');

select * from entity_table;
1562839624583 | $99999999999.999999 | 99999999999.510136  | 1                
1562839631250 | &999999999990.999999 | 99999999999.510136  | 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you populating the Kafka topic? KSQL currently only supports string keys. If you can't change how the topic is populated you could do:

```
CREATE STREAM entity_src WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC = 'pisos', VALUE_FORMAT='avro');

CREATE STREAM entity_rekey AS SELECT * FROM entity_src PARTITION BY ID;

CREATE TABLE entity_table with (KAFKA_TOPIC='entity_rekey', VALUE_FORMAT='AVRO');
```

BTW you don't need to specify the schema if you are using Avro.

Comment: I was specifying the schema because I want a subset of the data, as the document could have tens of fields.

Anyway, I think that i found my problem, the solution could be to use an extra stream as you suggest. The problem is that KSQL is ingnoring the "WITH (KEY = 'Id')" part of my create table, and it's using the topic key as the table key. I didn't found first because i was using a field with the same data that the key of the topic, but if i use "WITH (KEY = 'otherId')", Instead of using my otherId  as the table key, is still using the topic key.

Comment: Yes, that is KSQL's current behaviour. It uses the key of the topic. If `ROWKEY` doesn't match the column you specify, then you will see the problems you have had.

Comment: See https://docs.confluent.io/current/ksql/docs/developer-guide/join-streams-and-tables.html#join-requirements

Comment: well, creating another stream with with the "partition by" to rekey the stream worked. It's also documentend on the ksql docs at: https://docs.confluent.io/current/ksql/docs/developer-guide/syntax-reference.html#what-to-do-if-your-key-is-not-set-or-is-in-a-different-format  

thanks!